# TYPO3 Powermail: How do I add my custom fields to the export?

Tags: php, html, export, typo3, powermail

Powermail: 2.25.2
TYPO3: 6.2.19

I added a dynamic **custom field** to Powermail within a new extension and want to have the value included in the **csv export**. If I use the **Powermail Module** and expand the export block, there is a possibility to add additional fields to the export. Unfortunately, my custom field is not listed there.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

From checking the template `Resources/Private/Partials/Module/Export.html` I had the idea, to add it to the template, but wasn't sure which ID.

After some debugging through the extension I realized, that my custom field can easy be added to the `ul.extended_export_field` by the mentioned template, because it was already in the `{page.fields}` array. The condition for `{field.advancedFieldType}` prevented rendering the custom field, because it's type isn't in the advanced and basic fields.

You have therefore **2 solutions** to fix that:

1. change `Classes/Domain/Model/Field.php` within your extension
   and extend the `$advancedFieldTypes` or `$basicFieldTypes` array
2. change the template `Resources/Private/Partials/Module/Export.html`
   by adding a condition for your custom field type and render it into the list like `<li id="{field.uid}">{field.title} <span class="info">(<f:translate key="FormField" />)</span></li>`

**What I still not know** is how to manipulate the output within the export.

**Update:**

Output can be modified within
`Resources/Private/Templates/Module/ExportCsv.html`

Answer (score 1):

In at least powermail 4.4.0 you can configure the exportability of custom fields with TypoScript:

```
tx_powermail.flexForm.type.addFieldOptions.myfield.export = 1
```

This is described in the powermail documentation:  https://github.com/in2code-de/powermail/blob/master/Documentation/ForDevelopers/AddNewFields.md

Comment: The doc link is a 404, I believe the powermail documentation is no long being rendered on docs.typo3.org, so insteaf of https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForDevelopers/AddNewFields/Index.html it should be https://github.com/in2code-de/powermail/blob/master/Documentation/ForDevelopers/AddNewFields.md. Will change this, please check if correct.